# What is the difference between Cabal and Stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Yesterday I learnt about a new Haskell tool called [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack). At the first blush, it looks like it does much the same job as Cabal. So, what is the difference between them? Is stack a replacement for Cabal? In which cases should I use Stack instead of Cabal? What can Stack do that Cabal can't?

Comment: https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/announcing-first-public-beta-stack (in short it kindof replaces `cabal-install` and uses stackage as much as possible - there might be some back-integration into cabal-install at some point and I think the community is not sure if this is a good thing or not, because it might split the community)

Comment: AFAIU stack is handy to quickly work on an existing project. If you start something from scratch, you will certainly have to use cabal.

Comment: @mb14 That's not the case. You can use stack to start projects from scratch. In fact, stack templates provides an easy way to do that.

Comment: See this short article for a good overview: https://www.scs.stanford.edu/16wi-cs240h/labs/stack.html

Answer (score 119, accepted):

> Is stack a replacement for Cabal?

Yes and No.

> In which cases should I use Stack instead of Cabal? What can Stack do that Cabal can't?

Stack uses the curated stackage packages by *default*. That being so, any dependencies are known to build together, avoiding version conflict problems (which, back when they were commonplace in the Haskell experience, used to be known as "cabal hell"). Recent versions of Cabal also have measures in place to prevent conflict. Still, setting up a reproducible build configuration in which you know exactly what will be pulled from the repositories is more straightforward with Stack. Note that there is also provision for using non stackage packages, so you are good to go even if a package isn't present in the stackage snapshot.

Personally, I like Stack and would recommend every Haskell developers to use it. Their development is *fast*. And it has a **much** better UX. And there are things which Stack does which Cabal yet doesn't provide:

- Stack even downloads GHC for you and keeps it in an isolated location.
- Docker support (which is very convenient for deploying your Haskell applications)
- [Reproducible Haskell script](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/scripts/): You can pinpoint version of a package and can get guarantee that it will always execute without any problem. ([Cabal also has a script feature](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-run), but fully ensuring reproducibility with it is not quite as straightforward.)
- Ability to do `stack build --fast --file-watch`. This will automatically rebuild if you change the local files present. Using it along with `--pedantic` option is a deal-breaker for me.
- Stack supports creating projects using [templates](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates). It also supports your own custom templates.
- Stack has built-in [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack) support in it. It provides an alternative (IMO, a better) way of writing cabal files using yaml file which is more widely used in the industry.
- Intero has a smooth experience [when working with Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero/blob/master/TOOLING.md).

There is a nice blog post explaining the difference: [Why is Stack not Cabal?](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/why-is-stack-not-cabal) While Cabal has, in the intervening years since that post, evolved so as to overcome some of the issues discussed there, the discussion of the design goals and philosophy behind Stack remains relevant.

Comment: Has there been any changes since cabal 3 has been released?

Comment: @WilliamRusnack Yes, there have. Primarily, the default Cabal workflow now incorporates dependency conflict avoidance, though the strategy it uses to do so is noticeably different from Stack's. (@Sibi: I have taken the liberty to update your answer so that it better reflect where things stand these days.)

Answer (score 59):

In what follows, I will refer to the two tools being compared as *cabal-install* and *stack*. In particular, I will use *cabal-install* to avoid confusion with the *Cabal* library, which is common infrastructure used by both tools.

Broadly speaking, we can say *cabal-install* and *stack* are frontends to *Cabal*. Both tools make it possible to build Haskell projects whose sets of dependencies might conflict with each other within the confines of a single system. The key difference between them lies in how they address this goal:

- By default, *cabal-install* will, when asked to build a project, look at the dependencies specified in its `.cabal` file and use a dependency solver to figure out a set of packages and package versions that satisfy it. This set is drawn from [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/) as a whole -- all packages and all versions, past and present. Once a feasible build plan is found, the chosen version of the dependencies will be installed and indexed in a database somewhere in `~/.cabal`. Version conflicts between dependencies are avoided by indexing the installed packages according to their versions (as well as other relevant configuration options), so that different projects can retrieve the dependency versions they need without stepping on each other's toes. This arrangement is what the *cabal-install* documentation means by ["Nix-style local builds"](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix-local-build.html#how-it-works).
- When asked to build a project, *stack* will, rather than going to Hackage, look at the `resolver` field of [`stack.yaml`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/). In the default workflow, that field specifies a [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/) *snapshot*, which is a subset of Hackage packages with *fixed* versions that are known to be mutually compatible. *stack* will then attempt to satisfy the dependencies specified in the `.cabal` file (or possibly [the `project.yaml` file](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#does-stack-support-the-hpack-specification) -- different format, same role) using only what is provided by the snapshot. Packages installed from each snapshot are registered in separate databases, which do not interfere with each other.

We might say that the *stack* approach trades some setup flexibility for straightforwardness when it comes to specifying a build configuration. In particular, if you know that your project uses, say, the LTS 15.3 snapshot, you can go to [its Stackage page](https://www.stackage.org/lts-15.3) and know, at a glance, the versions of any dependency *stack* might pull from Stackage. That said, both tools offer features that go beyond the basic workflows so that, by and large, each can do all that the other does (albeit possibly in a less convenient manner). For instance, there are ways to [freeze exact versions of a known good build configuration](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-freeze) and to [solve dependencies with an old state of Hackage](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-index-state) with *cabal-install*, and it is possible to [require non-Stackage dependencies or override snapshot package versions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#extra-deps) while using *stack*.

Lastly, another difference between *cabal-install* and *stack* which is big enough to be worth mentioning in this overview is that *stack* aims at providing a complete build environment, with features such as [automatic GHC installation management](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#i-already-have-ghc-installed-can-i-still-use-stack) and [Docker integration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/docker_integration/). In contrast, *cabal-install* is meant to be orthogonal to other parts of the ecosystem, and so it doesn't attempt to provide this sort of feature (in particular, GHC versions have to be installed and managed separately, for instance through [the ghcup tool](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/)).

Answer (score 14):

From what I can glean from the FAQ, it seems that Stack uses the Cabal library, but not the `cabal.exe` binary (more correctly known as cabal-install). It looks like the aim of the project is automatic sandboxing and avoidance of dependency hell.

In other words, it uses the same Cabal package structure, it just provides a different front-end for managing this stuff. (I think!)

Comment: Apart from `cabal`, their source code seem to be also using `docker`. Although I don't know if they use that yet.

Comment: @Sibi Yes, it looks like you can optionally throw stuff into Docker, and it's meant to work. I haven't looked at it much further...