# How do I find the name of a package in Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am trying to include Control.Monad.State.Lazy in my stack project, but I cannot figure out what package I must include in package.yaml dependencies.

I usually end up guessing it, but I can't find it this time. What is the correct way to find the name of the package dependency in stack?

Comment: I don't know about stack, but https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Control.Monad.State.Lazy says it's part of `mtl`.

Comment: That worked, i'll use this in the future I guess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855060/126014

Comment: Another place to search: https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.22/hoogle?q=Control.Monad.State.Lazy

Answer (score 1):

On stackage.org, you can view the list of all modules in a snapshot, and which package they are found in:

https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.21/docs