# Where I can find a list of corresponding names for Stack's package.yaml, knowing package name from Import sentence in a code in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How we can find a "name" of package to include in package.yaml in list of dependences, which is corresponds to a particular "import" sentence in a haskell source file?
For instance.
In a hs source code I need to have something like

```
import Systm.Arch
```

What the name of the package to put into the package.yaml file in the list of dependences?
It should be something like:

```
... 
dependences:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- <package_name_corresponding_to "import System.Arch">
```

Where can I find such a list, suiteable for package.yaml or cabal file?
Thank you in advance.
P.S. For instance, if I had in hs code

```
import Data.Time
```

in package.yaml, I have this sting

```
- time
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find correct package name and version for Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854832/where-can-i-find-correct-package-name-and-version-for-haskell)

Comment: Yo can search this with [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=System.Arch&scope=set%3Astackage). For [`System.Arch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpu-0.1.2/docs/System-Arch.html), it is likely the [`cpu` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpu-0.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/). E.g. if you look for `Data.Map`, you see it is in the `containers` package (green text below the result): https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Data.Map&scope=set%3Astackage

Comment: Thanks. Yes. That's it. Green text below.