# How do I install Haskell Stack on Mac?

Tags: haskell

I have followed the instructions to install ghcup on my MacOS by following command:

```
curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh
```

But I couldn't install it, it prompted errors like these:

> Failed to install, consider updating this script via: ghcup upgrade
>   "ghcup --cache install" failed!

Comment: This is a v clear questoin and I have the same issue. This should not be downvoted imo.

Answer (score 2):

`stack` and `ghcup` are two different tools.

You can get `stack` from [this website](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/), which involves running the following command:

```sh
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
```

On the other hand, `ghcup` is a tool that only installs the Haskell compiler (GHC), which means that you won't be able to build a project using Stack. Note that this last installation comes with a build tool called `cabal`. You can learn the differences between `stack` and `cabal` [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913145/what-is-the-difference-between-cabal-and-stack).

Regarding your error with `ghcup`, I'd try to use the instructions from https://gitlab.haskell.org/haskell/ghcup. It is the main repo from the project, and probably updated faster. Note that you can use the "simple bootstrap" process, and if that doesn't work, try the manual one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have brew installed, you can use : `brew install stack`

Comment: `stack build` does not work from `brew` for me - and apparently not for the asker.